# Integrate print styles in Omega 4

Tags: 7, theming

What is the right or omega way of integrating print styles in omega 4?

I've found no references in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omega 4 layout styles are loaded last, even after print styles added via the theme's .info file. The only catch-all solution that I'm aware of is to an `@media` rule to your styles. If you need to override a layout's styles you'll need to add an `@media` rule there too.

If you're not using Omega 4 layouts then adding your print styles via the theme's .info file will work - just be aware that this will add an additional stylesheet request and so isn't the most performant option, especially considering how minimal print styles can often be. The `@media` solution wins on all fronts here IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Like for any css file, add it into the theme's info file, but rather than 'all', just specify it to be only for print.

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/everytime.css
stylesheets[screen][] = css/screen-only.css
stylesheets[print][] = css/print-only.css
```

Comment: So it's the same as any other theme? I thought omega might handle that part in its own way, like they do with preprocess functions and so on.

Comment: It's not the theme that handle them. Drupal just include them in every page.

Comment: Yeah, but as this is all based on sass, I thought there might be some boilerplate like they did with omega.hacks.scss, omega.no-query.scss and so on.

Comment: This won't work if you're using Omega 4 layouts and need to override a layout style in your print styles. See my answer below for a truly catch-all solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to the OMEGASUBTHEME.hacks.scss

```
@media print {

}
```